# Texture doesn't stretch properly. Why is this happening?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, textures, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL and Slick framework to load Textures to my OpenGL-application.

I'm using this image: [image: Japanese flag, using for texture]

And this code to import and utilize the texture:

```
    flagTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("japan.png"));
```

......

```
    flagTexture.bind();

    GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();

    GL11.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(2.5f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(2.5f, 2.5f);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0.0f, 2.5f);
    GL11.glEnd();

    GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

But the end-result becomes this:
[image: Texture not stretching to the vertex-parameters]

I'm not using any special settings like GL_REPEAT or anything like that. Whats going on? How can I make the texture fill the given vertices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the texture is getting padded out to the nearest power of two. There are two solutions here:

1. Stretch the texture out to the nearest power of two.
2. Calculate the difference between your texture's size and the nearest power of two and change the texture coordinates from `1.0f` to `textureWidth/nearestPowerOfTwoWidth` and `textureHeight/nearestPowerOfTwoHeight`.

There might also be some specific LWJGL method to allow for non-power-of-two textures, look into that.

Comment: Wow, solution 1 worked! Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this. Can you explain why this worked in contrast to the original width & height? Is it an opengl thing? Thanks.

Comment: OpenGL itself supports non-power-of-two textures since 2.0, this is an LWJGL thing. From what I've read, LWJGL still pads out textures to the nearest power of two (probably to support really old hardware). With the image you uploaded, your 600x400 image became a 1024x512 texture. OpenGL texture coordinates are scaled 0-1 in both the x and y axes. A texture coordinate (1, 1) represents (approximately) the pixel (1024, 512). You want pixel (600, 400), but in the 0-1 scale, so you scale it down to the that scale: (600/1024, 400/512)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support non-power-of-two textures, you can modify the loading method. If you use Slick2D, there's no way to do it other than to implement your "own" texture class (You can get some examples on those here: [Texture.java](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Examples%3aSpaceInvaders_Texture) and [TextureLoader.java](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Examples%3aSpaceInvaders_TextureLoader)
The TextureLoader class contains a method "get2Fold", this is used to calculate the next power of two bigger than the texture width/height. So, if you want to use textures with non-power-of-two size, just change this method to simply return fold; (=the input), so that the program "thinks" that the next power of two is the size of the image, which it isn't in many cases, but if the hardware supports it (Most does), this shouldn't be a problem. A more "abstract" way would be to change this line:
GL11.glTexImage2D(target, 0, dstPixelFormat, get2Fold(bufferedImage.getWidth()),                get2Fold(bufferedImage.getHeight()), 0, srcPixelFormat,             GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);
Here, the 4th argument = the width of the texture and the 5th = the height of the texture. If you set these to the IMAGE's width/height, it will work. Since this method is basically the same as the one before, there are the same problems for both.. As said before, this will slow down your image processing, and it might not be supported..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this link will be of some help

http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_1_-_Loading_Images_for_LWJGL

looks like its very similar to what your doing here.

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
GL11.glVertex2f(100,100);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(),100);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(),100+texture.getTextureHeight());
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
GL11.glVertex2f(100,100+texture.getTextureHeight());
GL11.glEnd();
```

Comment: this will still produce the same issue, it's an issue with the texture coordinates, not the vertices.