# texture border when using pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, textures, pyglet

I tried to get into pyglet and opengl and come up with weird results when drawing a simple triangle with a texture. When drawing the triangle the texture appears to have black border. I tried to change min/mag_filter but there is no effect on the border.
Am i missing something important here ?

```
    img = pyglet.image.load('test.png')
    tex = img.get_texture()
    #left triangle
    vert = [0,0,0,100,100,100]
    #right triangle
    vert2 = [200,0,200,100,300,100]
    uv = [0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
    img.blit(200,200)

    pyglet.gl.glDisable(tex.target)
    pyglet.graphics.draw(3,pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLES,('v2f',tuple(vert2)))

    pyglet.gl.glEnable(tex.target)
    pyglet.gl.glBindTexture(tex.target,tex.id)
    pyglet.graphics.draw(3,pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLES,('v2f',tuple(vert)),('t2f',tuple(uv)))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what part of the image we're supposed to be looking at? I don't really see a 'black border' anywhere. (just a black background).

Comment: The two triangles at the bottom are of the same size the only difference is that one is drawn with the texture. [like that](http://imgur.com/6yWVB)

Comment: [Same thing with red background](http://i.imgur.com/y0WRO.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's pyglet padding your texture out to the next power of two and filling the rest of the texture with black instead of stretching.

There are two solutions to this problem, both of which I answered on an earlier SO question regarding LWJGL: [Texture doesn't stretch properly. Why is this happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568106/texture-doesnt-stretch-properly-why-is-this-happening/10568140#10568140)

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem here.