# Texture not filling entire quad

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d, texture2d

I have configured most of it to the letter of the slick tutorials but what I get is the png in the lower left corner filling only 3/4 of the quad the dimensions are 100x100 for the quad and the texture is to fill it entirely but for some reason I cant get wrapping to work(HELP!! if that is my mistake)

Code for registry:

```
public Form(String fileName, Frame frame) {
    try {
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture(
                "PNG",
                ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("img/" + fileName
                        + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.frame = frame;
    VectorFrame = a.constructVectorFrame(frame);
}
```

And the code for the rendering:

```
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Color.white.bind();
    texture.bind();
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2d(point.x, point.y);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2d(point.x, point.y + frame.maxY);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2d(point.x + frame.maxX, point.y + frame.maxY);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2d(point.x + frame.maxX, point.y);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    a.renderVectorFrame(point, VectorFrame);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slick forces you to use power-of-two textures. You have two ways to deal with this:

- use power-of-two textures (for example, 128x128)
- change the 1.0fs inside your glTexCoord2f() to width/(nearest power of 2) and height/(nearest power of 2)

Also, look at this SO question: [Texture doesn't stretch properly. Why is this happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568106/texture-doesnt-stretch-properly-why-is-this-happening)

Comment: Might I ask why it does that?

Comment: @WilliamGourley videocards made after ~2006 don't have any problem with non power-of-two (NPOT) textures, but before that, they could use only NPOT textures. Probably, Slick forces it to have compatibility with older graphical cards. If you are interested in why power-of-two textures are used, take a look at this question on [GameDev stackexchange site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent). In brief, that's because graphical card hardware is optimized for matrix operation, vectors and lowlevel byte operations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy way to do it. Use texture.getWidth()/getHeight() when setting the TextureCoordinates. Works perfectly for me

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
Color.white.bind();
texture.bind();
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
GL11.glVertex2d(point.x, point.y);

GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, texture.getHeight()); // <---

GL11.glVertex2d(point.x, point.y + frame.maxY);

GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight()); // <---

GL11.glVertex2d(point.x + frame.maxX, point.y + frame.maxY);

GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), 0); // <---

GL11.glVertex2d(point.x + frame.maxX, point.y);
GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

a.renderVectorFrame(point, VectorFrame);
```