# Why does opengl only render correctly if texture sizes are powers of 2?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

When I load a texture using slick-util and render it using lwjgl's opengl, it is highly distorted unless the length and width of the texture are both powers of 2. Why is this?

Comment: old OpenGL and old hardware were limited to po2 textures because it's simpler to tile or swizzle the texture (for spatial coherency). see http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/texture-tiling-and-swizzling/

Comment: So theres no real workaround?

Comment: There are always workarounds. You should show and image with the geometry, the distortions and possibly a code showing your uv's. The problem is likely unrelated to the support of non-po2 textures.

Comment: What class are you using in lwjgl for using the GL functionality ?

Comment: @a.lasram: That being said, OpenGL-2 and later no longer has this limitation.

Comment: Check out this SO answer, it has workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568106/texture-doesnt-stretch-properly-why-is-this-happening

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be, that your unpack alignment is set improperly. The default alignment is 4 bytes. And power of 2 sized images usually fullfill that requirement.

Try what happens if you add a call `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` right before calling `glTexImage` or `glTexSubImage`.